# PHP SELECT query leaderboard

Tags: php

I am trying to display a leaderboard on my website. All of the times (lower is better) and usernames that they belong to are stored in the database. I would like to display the 10 lowest times along with the username. This block of code does what I want, but I am not sure if it is a safe solution.

I read that I need to use PDO when I have variables in the query, but I do not know if that applies to this.

```
<?php
        require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
 
        $sql = "SELECT score, uidUsers FROM numbersleaderboard ORDER by score ASC LIMIT 10";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["score"]. " - " . $row["uidUsers"]. "<br>";
        }
        $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: For this, is totally secure, since, there is no user input in your query. But anyway, it's much more better, if you use PDO, or mysqli in OOP mode.

I suggest to you the mysqli, PDO is overkill, you won't change your database from MySql I suppose.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: For PDO, that is for when you are dealing with user input since you can't trust user input. However, you aren't using variables, your SQL command is safe as there is no input from a user that will be passed to it.